# Getting the mouse coordinates in the WM_LBUTTONDOWN message

Tags: c++, winapi

the structure of `MSG` as followed:

```
typedef struct tagMSG {
  HWND   hwnd; 
  UINT   message; 
  WPARAM wParam; 
  LPARAM lParam; 
  DWORD  time; 
  POINT  pt; 
} MSG, *PMSG;
```

the message procedure as followed:

```
long WINAPI WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT iMessage, UINT wParam, LONG lParam)
```

**My Question**: In the message procedure, why it doesn't pass the `POINT` variable to window procedure, and how to find mouse's `POINT` ? By `GetCursorPos()` ? I find some example get it by `LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam)` directly.. can you tell me the information about it ? thank you...

i had see someone write this, is it right ? i not sure:

```
RECT rect1;
long WINAPI WndProc(HWND hWnd,UINT iMessage,UINT wParam,LONG lParam)
{
    HDC hDC;        
    WORD x,y;   
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;     

    x = LOWORD(lParam); 
    y = HIWORD(lParam);

    switch(iMessage)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        if(wParam&MK_CONTROL)
        {
            rect1.left = x; 
            rect1.top = y;
        }
        else if(wParam&MK_SHIFT)
        {
            rect1.left = x; 
            rect1.top = y;
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    default:
        return(DefWindowProc(hWnd,iMessage,wParam,lParam));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does the first half of your question have to do with the second?

Comment: i just want to say, when we GetMessage(xx), we get the Mouse'point, but in the process-function, it disappear, why windows do that?  my english is so poor, what i said is clear ? thank you...

Comment: Can I vote down based on your title?

Comment: I;ve also correct your "process function" to "window procedure" as it would just confuse things more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In the process function, why it doesn't pass the POINT variable to process function, and how to find mouse's POINT ?

There are separate functions to retrieve that information if you really want it.  Most message handlers don't deal with mouse input, and there's no point in passing around extra arguments for message handlers that will almost never use them. (Arguably `WndProc` could have been defined to take a `MSG*`; I don't know the reason for its design, but I'd guess that members were added to the `MSG` structure over time.)

> By GetCursorPos() ?

No. `GetCursorPos` will return the *current* position of the cursor, which might be different from the position when the message was generated.  You instead want [`GetMessagePos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644938.aspx). (This is analogous to [`GetAsyncKeyState` versus `GetKeyState`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/30/272262.aspx).)

Similarly, a message handler can obtain the message time through [`GetMessageTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644939.aspx).

Comment: @Mr.Tu:  In your example, the meanings of `lParam` and `wParam` are dependent on the message type, so it's very misleading to try to extract coordinate data before examining the message type.  It's also wrong to use `LOWORD` and `HIWORD` to extract coordinates; you need to use `GET_X_LPARAM` and `GET_Y_LPARAM` to properly handle negative coordinates on multi-monitor systems.

Comment: um.. there is macro's for doing this stuff.. the High bits of the LPARAM is the x , the LOW bit is y (if memory serves me correctly). see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @johnathon: Huh?  Yes, those macros are `GET_X_LPARAM` and `GET_Y_LPARAM` as I mentioned in my comment (and as mentioned on that page you linked to).

Answer (score 4):

The coordinates do not disappear. They are in `lParam`. See [WM_MOUSEMOVE message on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645616%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
A window receives this message through its WindowProc function.
...
lParam

    The low-order word specifies the x-coordinate of the cursor.
The coordinate is relative to the upper-left corner of the client area.

    The high-order word specifies the y-coordinate of the cursor.
The coordinate is relative to the upper-left corner of the client area.
...
Use the following code to obtain the horizontal and vertical position:

xPos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
```

Comment: yes, it right, because it was limited to WM_MOUSEMOVE, how about it doesn't belong to mouse's message, such as WM_KEYDOWN, WM_CHAR, then i can do this also?  xPos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
thanks for your answer...

Comment: Why don't you just read about [WM_KEYDOWN message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [WM_CHAR message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: How does that update make the question different and how do we know if the code is correct if we don't know what it's supposed to be doing and if `rect1` is undefined?

Comment: oh, i am sorry, i forget that rect1 is defined before process-function, RECT rect1;